# Cider-connect to already running REPL with figwheel

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurescript, cider

I'm trying to `cider-connect` to an already running repl, launched by the following: `lein trampoline with-profile more-figwheel figwheel app test`. 
That will launch and run my figwheel application with no problem. The problem arise when I try to `cider-connect-cljs` to it.
I choose `localhost` as `host` and then I select my the port suggested `xxx:7889` and then I choose `figwheel`. The repl is launched, with these 
error messages:

```
WARNING: CIDER requires nREPL 0.4.4 (or newer) to work properly
         More information.
WARNING: CIDER requires cider-nrepl to be fully functional. Many things will not work without it!
         More information.
```

In my `~/.lein/profiles.clj` I have this however

```
{:user 
 {:dependencies [[[nrepl "0.6.0"]]
  :plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.18.0-SNAPSHOT"]
            [refactor-nrepl "2.4.0-SNAPSHOT"]]

  :figwheel {:nrepl-middleware ["refactor-nrepl.middleware/wrap-refactor"
                                "cider.nrepl/cider-middleware"]}}}
```

But I still get the warnings. I also get this error sometimes `‘autopair-newline’ requires the nREPL op "classpath" (provided by cider-nrepl)`
Sometimes with something other than 'autopair-newline'.

**I'm using**:
Emacs: GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2018-05-29
Cider: CIDER 0.21.0 (New York)
Lein: Leiningen 2.9.1 on Java 1.8.0_191 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: Is that a direct paste from your project.clj as the nrepl dep doesn’t seem to have closed the ].

Comment: Running cider 0.21 with cider-nrepl 0.18 snapshot is unlikely to work - there’s been quite a few changes lately.

Comment: What do you see in the REPL welcome message exactly? With this warning you can't possibly be on nREPL 0.6 (which is the default with Lein 2.9.1).

Comment: You are right. ;; CIDER 0.21.0 (New York), nREPL 0.2.13

Comment: Well, it seems you're not using Lein 2.9.1. Check your local setup.

Comment: I am now getting this: ;; CIDER 0.21.0 (New York), nREPL 0.6.0

I am using these deps:  [nrepl "0.6.0"]
                                      [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.18"]
                                      [cider/piggieback "0.4.0"]

with these plugins: [cider/cider-nrepl "0.21.0"]
                              [lein-figwheel "0.5.18"]

But I get this warning when the repl opens after a cider-connect-cljs: WARNING: CIDER requires cider-nrepl to be fully functional. Many things will not work without it!

Comment: In *messages* I get "user-error: ‘autopair-newline’ requires the nREPL op "classpath" (provided by cider-nrepl)", do you think it's related?